# Make changes on existing Grail package and publish it

Tags: grails, package

I have some old grails package that was developed in our group many years ago. No source code - zip only.
I would like to make a tiny change in this package and republish it again with a different version. So:

1. I downloaded a package zip file from a repository
2. Do a change.
3. While trying to run a "package-plugin" command I receive an error since
   grails cannot compile the project which is understandable because I
   have only a package and NOT a source code.

What should I do repackage my new package and create a new grails package?

Comment: When you say "package", do you mean "plugin"? Ultimately, if you don't have the source code for the plugin you're trying to change, you won't be able to modify it.

Comment: Yes, it's a plugin. The modification is a png file replacing so it should be very minor change